# ReCaptcha API with different language on android

Tags: android, recaptcha, multilingual, safetynet-api

I am using reCaptcha API on android through [SafetyNet API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#java) as given on Android Developer site.
My application is multilingual application. When I all together change phones language setting, my reCaptcha appears in that language. But I want to change language according to selected locale on app level without changing phone language settings. Google docs has given language codes [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language). Can anyone help me with implementing this thing. Any help or any suggestion will be appreciated.

This is my current code. This works with default phone language very well. I explored available methods for specifying language but no luck.

```
public void verify() {
        SafetyNetClient client = SafetyNet.getClient(activity);
        Task<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse> verifierTask = client.verifyWithRecaptcha(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.site_key));
        verifierTask.addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse recaptchaTokenResponse) {
                        String userResponseToken = recaptchaTokenResponse.getTokenResult();
                        if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
                            new CaptchaVerificationTask().execute(userResponseToken);
                        } else {
                            captchaVerificationListener.onFailure();
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).addOnFailureListener(activity, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                    // An error occurred when communicating with the
                    // reCAPTCHA service. Refer to the status code to
                    // handle the error appropriately.
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                    int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                    Log.d("Login ReCaptcha", "Error: " + CommonStatusCodes
                            .getStatusCodeString(statusCode));
                } else {
                    // A different, unknown type of error occurred.
                    Log.d("Login ReCaptcha", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                captchaVerificationListener.onFailure();
            }
        });
    }
```